# Returning a list from an iterated object in Python

Tags: python

I need help creating a list of iterated values. In this example, I want to get all odd numbers in the range of x. Then make a list from it:

```
def x_list(x):  
    for i in range(x):  
        if x%2==0:  
            return i
```

Since return stops the function after iterating through the first object, I'm unable to get the rest of the values and create a list from it.
Could you advice what I should use instead of "return"?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `ret` as a list at the top of the function, fill it within the loop.

After the loop ends, return it.

```
def x_list(x):  
    ret = []
    for i in range(x):  
        if i%2==0:  
            ret.append(i)
    return ret
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my initial code, it's my first post and I'm still figuring out proper format.

Comment: No problem..  You have a button with brackets `{}`, press this button and it will generate a code area for you

Comment: Generator functions are preferable to this style of accumulator, _especially_ since the op is /almost/ there already.

Comment: @hop , The OP seems a beginner to python. Starting with generators seems a bit harsh. Also I don't think that the OP intention was to implement it as a generator.

Comment: @omri_saadon: they already /almost/ got there on their own. beginner or not.

Comment: @hop , He is not almost there.. He doesn't know  the difference between `return` and `yield` which is all the concept of generators. Even though that replacing `return` with `yield` solve the issue doesn't mean that he was close\almost there.

Comment: @omri_saadon: you are arguing from the perspective of someone starting out with a language that doesn't have generator functions. if you are new to the whole thing _now_, yield (although with a strange name) is a very natural concept.

Comment: At least now I'm aware of generators and can start learning it :)

Comment: @gidHxly , That's for sure :) Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

If you use `yield` instead of `return`, then you should be able to iterate through the whole range. This example will print out the even numbers.

```
def x_list(x):  
    for i in range(x):  
        if i%2==1:  
            yield i

for n in x_list(10):
    print(n)
```

I also assume you want `if i%2==1:` not `if x%2==0:`, otherwise you'll get every number instead of just the odd ones.

Based on hop's suggestion, you could also do this:

```
evens = range(0, 10, 2)

for n in evens:
    print(n)
```

Where the 3rd parameter in `range` is the step size

Comment: You should show the better way of using `range()` with a step parameter as well.

Answer (score 0):

With range, you can specify a stepping.

Therefore, all you need to do is:

```
def oddlist(x):
    return list(range(1, x, 2))
```

If you don't actually need a list, and just an iterable will do, you could omit the list generation:

```
def oddlist(x):
    return range(1, x, 2)
```